# Using jinja2 to show a different image per carousel click

Tags: html, carousel

I am trying to show a carousel with different random images showing per click, at the minute random images are showing but it is the same image on each carousel.
Here is my index.html:

```
<div class="car-container">
        <div id="carouselExampleControlsNoTouching" class="carousel slide" data-bs-touch="false" data-bs-interval="false">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
    {% for pics in featuredimage %}
    
        <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename=pics ) }}">
    
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
    <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename=pics ) }}">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
    <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename=pics ) }}">
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
  </div>
  
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControlsNoTouching" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControlsNoTouching" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The `<div></div>` tags won't match if you have more than one pic in `featuredimage`.

Comment: So using different divs will fix it?

Comment: Nope, I meant you should close the div tag inside the for loop, like `{% for ... %} <div ...><img ...></div> {% endfor %}`. Do not repeat the div tags manually, otherwise you'll have the same image multiple times.

Comment: This is what I have done atm but still no luck, could be wrong though but they still show the same image. `{% for pics in featuredimage %}
    <div class="carousel-item active">
  <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename=pics ) }}">
    </div>
 {% endfor %}
 {% for pics in featuredimage %}
    <div class="carousel-item">
  <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename=pics ) }}">
    </div>
 {% endfor %}
 {% for pics in featuredimage %}
    <div class="carousel-item">
  <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename=pics ) }}">
    </div>
 {% endfor %}
  </div>`